# (Не) время для любви - можно ли заключать частицу в скобки?

Tags: приставка

https://artguide.com/events/15127:

(Не) время для любви
О роли современного музея в развитии культуры памяти и новых подходах к репрезентации трагедии.

Что значит "(не) время"?

Автор имеет в виду, что неизвестно, время ли сейчас для любви.

В русском языке можно ли так писать: в скобках частица или приставка? Например, (не)уважение.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь "**не**" в скобках означает "**рассуждение**".

То есть: **ход** принятия решения "**Время** для любви" или "***Не* время** для любви".

Так писать **можно**, но если учитывать моё мнение, то я не советую.